# Mutli relationships with Eloquent and Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 6 tables:

```
permissions:
id
permission_name

roles:
id
role_name

user_roles:
id 
user_id 
role_id

user_permissions:
id 
user_id 
permission_id

role_permissions:
id
role_id
permission_id

users:
id
username
email
```

Now I like to add a custom function into my Eloquent model for *permissions* named *getUsersWithPermission()*.

Now it is possible that user has the permission by the role he has given (user table join on user_roles, join that table on role_permissions and last that table join on permissions.

Or the user has a specific permission set in the user_permissions table (join user_permissions table on user table and join the permissions table on the user_permissions table)

How can I create a Eloquent model function that returns all the users with a specific permission say: "notification.error.process" where that is the permission name

A *hasMany* doesn't quite do what I want (and I cannot define multi tables in there). I am using Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your many-to-many relations correctly (User-Permission and User-Role-Permission), the following should do the trick:

```
$permissionName = 'notification.error.process';
$usersWithPermission = User::whereHas('permissions', function($query) use ($permissionName) {
  $query->whereName($permissionName);
})->orWhereHas('roles.permissions', function($query) use ($permissionName) {
  $query->whereName($permissionName);
})->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean bij defined your many-to-many relations correctly?

Comment: You didn't post your model code so I can only assume you defined relations in there. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I understand how to create the relationship to the user_permission table however your second piece of code `>orWhereHas('roles.permissions', function($query) use ($permissionName) {
  $query->whereName($permissionName);
})->get();` I still dont get how do I setup the relationship in the model for that? Or do I need to create the relationship in the "RolePermission" model?

Comment: You don't need to create models for intermediate tables like user_permission or role_permission. You need to create many to many relationships between users and permissions, users and roles and then roles and permissions, like in the docs. Then you'll be able to use the query above. It returns all users that have a `permissions` record with given name and users that have a `roles` record that in turn has `permissions` record with given name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand your table structure using this ER diagram.

[image: model ER diagram of your table structure]

TO handle this situation, You may create 3 'Eloquent Models'

1. User
2. Role
3. Permission

in every model you may create `belongsToMany()` relationship to each other models.

one example, On 'User Model'

```
public function permissions()
{
    // need to define any other differences in your tables foreign keys as  2nd, 3rd parameters and so on.
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

Now you need to get all the users 'whom has a role which has the privilege' **OR** 'whom directly has the privilege.

to do so.

```
$users = User::whereHas('privileges', function($query) {
    $query->where('permission_name', 'notification.error.process');
})->orWhereHas('roles.permissions', function($query) {
    $query->where('permission_name', 'notification.error.process');
})->get();
```

I hope you will get an idea. your code may be slightly different from mine. but this is the concept.